# Is it possible to use a proxy rotator such as crawlera with google trends?

Tags: python, proxy, web-crawler, google-trends

Since google trends require you to login, can I still use an IP rotator such as crawlera to download the csv files? If so, is there any example code with python (i.e python + crawlera to download files on google).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No one is going to write code for you.

But I can leave some comments because I have been using Crawlera proxies for the past few months.

With crawlera you can scrape Google Trends with new IP each time, or even you can use a same IP each time(its called session management in crawlera).

You can send a header `'X-Crawlera-Session':'create'` along with your request and Crawlera on their end will create a session, and in response, they will return `'X-Crawlera-Session': ['123123123']` ... And if you think that you are not blocked from Google,

You can send `'X-Crawlera-Session': '123123123'` with each of your request so Crawlera will use same IP each time.

Answer (score 0):

There is example of code with many languages in the documentation.
See https://doc.scrapinghub.com/crawlera.html#python for Python example.